# Откуда IntelliJ берет путь до gradle при создании проекта?

Tags: intellij-idea

При создании проекта указываю Java 18. Idea не даёт создать проект.
ошибка :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, вопрос. Откуда берется 7.4 и как мне явно изменить версию gradle через интерфейс Idea до создания проекта (понятное дело, что после создания можно поднять легко) ?
Gradle_home не задана, в path ничего нет.

Comment: Текущая версия Gradle не поддерживает JDK 18, установленный на вашей системе.  Нужно либо установить JDK 16, либо апгрейдить Gradle до версии 7.4, в котором будет поддержка JDK 18.

Comment: Неверно. Поддержка Java 18 идёт с 7.5. Он как раз ругается  на 7.4, которую среда берет из какой то папки у себя (впрочем, уже методом тыка нашел, что встроенный плагин Idea Gradle(plugins/gradle) как раз в релизной версии завязан на 7.4. то есть, дело в том, что Jetbrains не обновили плагин ещё).